# Как подключиться к серверу через bash в MacOS?

Tags: php, bash, ssh

Открыл bash. Написал там команду: ssh [login]@[ip-server]

Нажимаю Enter. Bash никак не реагирует, подключение к виртуальному серверу не происходит, запрос пароля не происходит.

Почему так?

Comment: Ну тоесть ваша команда имеет вид `ssh login@ip_servers` без квадратных скобок? Я правильно понимаю? Я прошу не обижаться на вопрос, просто всякое бывает. И еще. Тоесть вообще никакой реакции или все таки что-то выдает? А вообще не морочтесь с маковским башем. Поставьте через `brew` нормальный. Да и `sed` и `awk` так-же поменяйте на GNU версии

Comment: ssh -v login@server что пишет 

Comment: `nc -l ip-server 22` что пишет?

Comment: nc: getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Comment: @DmitryNikitin добавте в вопрос **полный** лог того что вы вводите в оболочку и что она вам выдает в ответ на команды `nc -l ip-server 22; ping ip-server` где `ip-server` должен быть ваш  IPv4 адресс виртуального сервера.